# famd process - lsof -i

Tags: postfix, process

I'm running a postfix machine with courier on it. I did a **lsof -i** and I got the following

```
famd      1437     root    3u  IPv4   3916       TCP localhost.localdomain:webster (LISTEN)
```

Does anybody know what's famd and webster? I dont recall seeing this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`famd` is the File Access Modification Daemon, described as "FAM monitors files and directories, notifying interested applications of changes."

As far as the port goes, sometimes ports get used by different applications.  `webster` is just the network dictionary, which isn't widely used; you're just seeing it because your `/etc/services` has `webster` listed for port 765 instead of `fam`.

Answer (score 1):

`famd` is a daemon that watches filesystems for access and modifications. It's a more generic cross-platform implementation of a scheme similar to inotify.

It uses a TCP socket to communicate with other programs that set watches on it, as well as remote machines that want to set up watches on NFS shares.